# NPM error when trying to install react-qr-reader

Tags: reactjs, npm

Hey I got this issue when I run `npm i react-qr-reader` in terminal, any solutions? I'm trying to implement a QR code scanner for my web app.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: kiosk-system@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-qr-reader@3.0.0-beta-1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-qr-reader
npm ERR!   react-qr-reader@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\dasun\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-26T12_31_12_014Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dasun\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-26T12_31_12_014Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: This is rude and non-sense

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i react-qr-reader --legacy-peer-deps
```